# how much addresses does cryptocurrency wallets checks via derivation paths?

Tags: bitcoin, cryptocurrency, mnemonics

I generated a mnemonic 12-words seed.
I calculated the 2525 address via derivation path.
like m/84'/0'/0'/0/2525
Sent there a few satoshis.

Which popular wallets will scan entire range of paths from 1 to 2525 and show me actual balance?

guesses are good too.

Trying to check it by myself, but interested to listen people.

Answer (score -1):

You can import the wallet into the BlueWallet app and specify a custom range for it to generate addresses from. By default it'll only load the first 20 in the range, but you can tweak settings to increase it.

If that's not enough though you can install a more dedicated wallet, like Sparrow (preferred) or Electrum and those will give you a huge range of settings to import your wallet and use it.